# Selecionar dados de 2 tabelas PHP

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Boas pessoal, tenho aqui duas tabelas com a seguinte estrutura:
1 - Pedidos, 2 - Order_items.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: Order Items]

Eu preciso selecionar os dados de cada e exibir os detalhes da compra, exemplo:

Pedido #1 (tabela 1)
Cliente: Thales (tabela 1)
Lanches: lanche1, lanche2, lanche3 (tabela 2) (valor de cada lanche da tabela 2)
Endereço: Endereço do cliente (tabela 1)
Pagamento: Pagamento (tabela 1)
Status: Recebido (tabela 1)

Total: valor total (calcular da tabela 2)

Como eu poderia fazer isso? Já fiz várias tentativas, porém não estou conseguindo exibir corretamente.

Comment: Pode fazer essa consulta no SQL e trazer para o PHP. Como você faz a consulta ao BD?

Comment: Estou usando `SELECT pedidos.id, pedidos.client_id, pedidos.valor, pedidos.status, order_items.lanche_id, order_items.client_id FROM pedidos LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.client_id = pedidos.client_id GROUP BY pedidos.id DESC LIMIT 1` Porém, em lanches por exemplo, mesmo tendo mais de um, recebo apenas um. (Ex: Cliente comprou lanche1, lanche2, lanche3. Recebo de retorno apenas lanche1)

Comment: você está usando o `DESC LIMIT 1`, elimine o `LIMIT 1` e execute novamente.